# Pause Stopwatch Timer with Sleep Thread?

Tags: java, timer, thread-sleep

I'm trying to make a stopwatch in Java and don't know how to pause and continue my timer.  Here is what I have done so far.

```
startButton.addActionListener(this);
stopButton.addActionListener(this);
pauseButton.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    if (e.getSource() == startButton){
        start = aCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        startButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        stopButton.setBackground(null);
        pauseButton.setBackground(null);
    } else if (e.getSource() == stopButton) {
        stopButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        startButton.setBackground(null);
        pauseButton.setBackground(null);
        aJLabel.setText("Elapsed time is: " + 
                (double) (aCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - start) / 1000 );
    } else if (e.getSource() == pauseButton) {
        pauseButton.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        stopButton.setBackground(null);
        startButton.setBackground(null);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've only changed the colors for my pause button.  I don't really know how to pause the thread by having the user click on the button.  All examples I've found of thread.sleep() were with a specific time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swing.Timer (not util.Timer) like this:

```
int interval = 100; // set milliseconds for each loop
Timer timer = new Timer(interval, (evt) -> repeatingProccess());
// create the method  repeatingProccess() with your
// code that makes the clock tick


startButton.addActionListener(e -> timer.start());
stopButton.addActionListener( e -> {
    timer.stop(); 
    // here refresh your clock with some code... 
};
pauseButton.addActionListener(e -> timer.stop());
```

You write a method called `repeatingProccess()` and it works in its own thread again and again every `interval` milliseconds. For a clock that counts seconds you can do this:

```
int interval = 1000;
int seconds = 0;
public void repeatingProccess() {
    seconds++ ;
}
```

note: 
   The second will not be exactly 1000 milliseconds but around 1001 because of the time needed to run `seconds++` but you can fix that as well by getting System time before and after and substracting the difference from your clock. You should use the Calendar API for this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't realize there were two Timer classes. Can you explain what you mean by the repeatingProcess() method?  Is it supposed to be the display for the timer because I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I added some explanation.